# Can gcc -o and -S be used together

Tags: c, gcc

Can I use for example

> gcc -o -S output.s abs.c

to generate an assembly file with name output.s? It seems like I can't. When I try to do that, I got following error message.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I do not intend to use the linker, just try to examine the assembly code.

Comment: I seem to remember it can be, however the parameter order would be `gcc -S -o output.s abs.c`.

Comment: Good point! I bet you the OP has a "-S"  file in his directory. (Or actually, gcc refused to compile because it couldn't find output.s .)

Comment: to avoid invoking the linker, include the '-c' parameter,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-o` must be followed by the name of the output file. So, this would work:

```
gcc -S abc.c -o output.s
```